# Scale the values of two images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to scale the values of two images (imgA and imgB). This gets me into trouble. 
Both images are the same size. When the value of imgA is 0, the value of imgB equals 0.8. The scalar (imgB) rises parabolically to 1 when imgA equals 20, then falls to 0.8, when imgA equals 40.

In brief:

```
imgA   imgB
0      0.8
20     1
40     0.8
```

So what I'd like to know is how to write the code to accomplish this in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your example values, the function that seems to describe the relation between imgA and imgB is

```
 B = 1 - 0.2 * ( A/20 - 1 ) ^ 2
```

You can apply this to your matrices quite directly. To find the desired values for imgB:

```
imgB = 1 - 0.2 * ( imgA/20 - 1) .^ 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Junuxx, This must be a good way to normalize two images separately. But they should be interact with each other. As I mention above, if the value of imgA equals 0, the value of imgB should be 0.8 (imgA=0, imgB=0.8) if imgA equals 20, imgB should be 1, (imgA=20, imgB=1), if imgA equals 40, imgB falls to 0.8 again (imgA=40, imgB=0.8). I'm just guess, not sure whether relation operation is used for this purpose or not.

Comment: Ah. That was not clear to me. The question doesn't mention that you don't have imgB yet, it only describes the relation between imgA and imgB. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Junuxx. It works very well. I'd like to know where the formula come from? what is the fundamental principal to find out this?

Comment: Basic math, maybe you should (re)read something about quadratic algebra? Although my formula was a bit improvised, the proper form would be `-0.0005x² + 0.02x + 0.8`

Comment: Thank you for directing me to given topic in math? I'll read it. it seems you're really master in math:)